Ошибка: "provider: named pipes provider, error 40: - не удалось открыть подключение к sql server" при запуске программы на другом ПК
Всем привет!
Создал программку на C# с помощью Windows Forms (.NET Framework), которая использует БД.
На ПК она у меня прекрасно работает и таблицы из БД отображаются в программе.
Но при попытке открыть ее на ноуте мне выдает такую ошибку:
"При установлении соединения с sql server произошла ошибка связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. (provider: named pipes provider, error 40: - не удалось открыть подключение к sql server)"
На ПК использую Windows 10 Pro, SQL Server 2022, для входа в саму базу использую Windows Authentication.
Строка подключения у меня выглядит так:
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-03S0GAV;Initial Catalog=MusicAccessoryMonitoringDB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");

Мне необходимо, чтобы прога запускалась и работала правильно на других любых устройствах (например, на ПК друга, препода и т.д.).
На ПК TCP/IP в SQL Configuration Manager включен и порт 1433 прописан, в брандмауэре правило входящего подключения тоже создано, сервер перезапускал... Ничего не помогло...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Проблема в том, что вы не понимаете как работают сервера и как идет к ним подключение. SQL Server - ключевое тут "сервер", то есть это база данных, которая устанавливается и настраивается на одном компьютере (сервере) и к нему уже идет подключение с других компьютеров. В вашей строке подключения указано Data Source=DESKTOP-03S0GAV - что по сути означает localhost, а именно "только этот компьютер", да и уверен, что сам сервер у вас не настроен для доступа за пределы вашего PC. Другими словами, в строке подключения должен быть ваш IP адрес, открытый для подключения.

Что касается "например, на ПК друга, препода и т.д." - то это уже за пределами вашей сети и сети провайдера, а это значит, что ваш IP должен быть "белый", а также должен быть проброшен порт. Услуга "белый IP" обычно платная у провайдера, при ее покупке провайдер дает вам уникальный IP к которому можно подключиться за пределами сети провайдера. Так что, проблема у вас сейчас в то, что 1. Не то указано в сроке подключения. 2 У вас скорей всего нет доступа за пределами сети. 3. Не проброшен порт. 4. Сервер не настроен на прием внешних запросов. И да, если у вас учебный проект, то советую SQLite.

Понял, спасибо за объяснение)

И еще, подскажите пожалуйста, я изменил строку подключения на такую: SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=MusicAccessoryMonitoringDB;User ID=manager_admin;Password=passwd;TrustServerCertificate=True");
И теперь мне выводит уже другую ошибку: "При установлении соединения с sql server произошла ошибка связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение".

Я даже брандмауэр на ПК отключил (несмотря на то, что правило входящих подключений на порт 1433 там присутствует), TCP/IP включено в конфигурации сервера, порт прописан, ноутбук и ПК подключены к одной сети, должно же все работать?

Нет, не должно. 127.0.0.1 означает "Только этот компьютер", на другом компьютере вы не подключитесь по этому IP к серверу. У вас должен быть IP локальной сети (если нужно подключиться только в пределах локальной сети (обычно это 192.168.....). Если подключение за пределами вашей сети, то IP тот, что дает вам провайдер. И повторю, сам сервер должен быть настроен для разрешения этих подключений, как и должен быть проброшен порт (роутер).
